# Google Hangouts Chatbot Create Room

Tags: node.js, google-api, microservices, google-hangouts

I am writing service for messaging between rooms using Hangouts chatbot. Is it possible to create a room with Hangouts chatbot?

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts

Answer (score 4):

### If it were generally possible to create a new room programmaticaly with the Hangous API, you could do it with the chatbot.

For example, if you [implement the chatbox with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script), you can create a function [`onMessage(event)`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#manifest_file) and establish was will to happen in case of a certain `event.message.text` (e.g. create a new chat room if the message text contains the string `create new room`.

**However, for the moment it is not possible to create a new chat room programmatically.**

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/80447084) asking for this functionality, but given the potential of abuse, it is controversial either it will be implemented.

See comment #2:

> Hello, thank you for the feature request! At the moment rooms cannot
>   be created via the API to prevent abuse such as a bot or script
>   spamming room creation. However, this kind of feature has been
>   discussed internally and may be coming in the future (with
>   limitations). I will update this issue if more information is
>   released.

And comment #25:

> Thanks for the input. It's great to see some real life use cases. We
>   fully acknowledge the importance of a CreateRoom(DM) API and we are
>   actively looking into the right permission model to allow bots to do
>   so. Please continue to follow this bug as we will post updates here
>   when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much. @ziganotschka