# Google Calendar API - cannot create Google Hangout link with eventNamedHangout

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a Google Hangout link and insert it into a calendar event for a G-Suite account. My script is calling Calendar.Events.insert with below payload.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) I need to use **eventNamedHangout** as the type of conferenceSolutionKey but the API responded back with a Google Meet link instead.

I tried **eventHangout** but I am getting "invalid conference type value" error which I believe I should not use eventHangout as the type.

How can I create a Hangout link for this account?

```
payload = {
  "calendarId": "primary",
  "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
  "maxAttendees": 10,
  "sendNotifications": true,
  "sendUpdates": "all",
  "summary": 'My Event Summary',
  "description": 'My Event Description',
  "end": {
  "date": someDate1,  
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
  "start": {
    "date": someDate2,
      "timeZone": "America/New_York" 
  },
    "conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
          "type": "eventNamedHangout"
        },
          "requestId": someRandomString
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are a G Suite user, `eventNamedHangout` is the correct choice for you

### Do not feel put off because of obtaining a  `Google Meet link` instead of a `Google Hangout link`

Quote from the [googleblog](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/upcoming-hangouts-service-consolidation.html):

> Later this year, we'll transition classic Hangouts users on G Suite
> domains to Chat and Meet

More information about Google Meet: [here](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9545619?hl=en&ref_topic=7306097), [here](https://apps.google.com/meet/) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310169?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! From the blog post I learnt what I meant to achieve is to create a room in Hangouts Chat rather than a Hangouts Meet link. I have read your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724078/google-hangouts-chatbot-create-room and unfortunately we cannot create a Hangouts Chat room programmatically for now.