# Google Workspace - Create Space - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

Upon a Google Form being submitted, I want to cause a 'trigger' that creates a 'space' in google workspace.

[image]

I cannot find any documentation within GAS (Google Apps Script) that documents Google Workspaces.

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Due to the naming of the product google searches get confused when trying to create a 'space' within the recently re-named, google 'WorkSpace'.

Is there currently no support with Apps Script & 'Spaces'?

If there is, can you please link the documentation.. Perhaps it's listed in the documentation under a legacy name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Google's [Blog update](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/09/google-chat-rooms-are-now-spaces.html) on 8th September 2021:

> In June 2021, we announced that ‘Rooms’ in Google Chat would evolve to become ‘Spaces’. As part of that evolution, starting on September 8, 2021, any user who has enabled Chat in their Gmail settings will start to see the term ‘Rooms’ automatically updated to ‘Spaces’.

So to create a Space, one would need to create a Room in Google Chat; but unfortunately at the moment the [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat) doesn't allow creating Rooms/Spaces.

As Google Apps Script uses the Workspace APIs in its native functions, they are limited by the functionality of what the APIs can do too.

There is a feature request to add creation of Rooms/Spaces to the API which you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/80447084), giving it a star can help boost its priority. It does seem like it's on the way, but as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726179/11551468) it poses modes of abuse to may only come as a limited feature.

Comment: Please consider me relatively new to coding.

I'm assuming that google apps script is basically an IDE that 'makes life easy'. Is there any google cloud tech that means I can tap-into and create new google spaces? or is google apps scrip the only option to target google apis

Comment: It's just not possible programmatically at all - that's why it would be best to give the feature request a star.

Comment: Thank you ! I have stared as per your advice. Do you know if you can use the google tasks api to connect to an existing google space?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still searching about creating spaces, Spaces creation is now available as part of the Google Workspace Developer Preview Program.
Please see the link below:

https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/create