# Is it possible to duplicate a google space (Formally, google rooms)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-chat

Via Chat API or otherwise, is it possible to duplicate a google space?

[image: Duplicate, Google Space]

I have a 'template' space set up that has many tasks attached to it.

For each 'Job' I bring on in my small business, I want to create a Google Space for it and have the tasks automatically assigned to each staff member.

Manually creating a space for each job (50+ tasks per job, 4-5 jobs per week) must be automated.

Comment: [REST Resource: spaces]( https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces) doesn't include a method to create spaces. Apparently your best bet will be to use a web browser automation tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69738447/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. This is not possible because there is no way to programmatically create Google Spaces (aka Rooms).

This feature was discussed internally for some time but is not generally available until today. See this issue discussed on the related tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80447084?pli=1
In short, the main concern is this feature would be misused by bots, etc.